# How to solve $\int_{S_3^+(0)} \frac{e^w+z}{z+2} dw$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

In my lecture notes the following integral was computed:
\begin{align*}
\int_{S_3^+(0)} \frac{e^w+z}{z+2} dw.
\end{align*}

There is written: In order to use the Cauchy Integral formula, which is
\begin{align*}
f(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{S_R^+(a)} \frac{f(w)}{w-z} dw,
\end{align*}
we define $f(w) := e^w+w$ and $z := -2$. Clearly $f$ is differentiable in $\mathbb C$ and we obtain 
\begin{align*}
\int_{S_3^+(0)} \frac{e^w+z}{z+2} dw = 2\pi i (e^{-2}-2).
\end{align*}

Could please someone explain to me what happened here? I don't understand, why one can set $z = -2$ because then the integrand would not be defined any more? Furthermore I don't understand why the definition of $f$ should fit here.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: If I would change the path $S_3^+(0)$ to $S_1^+(0) = e^{it}$, $t \in [0,2\pi]$, then it turned out by the Deformation Theorem, that the integral is zero. And that is because $S_1^+(0)$ is homotopic to a point in $\mathbb C \setminus \{-2\}$. Could someone explain to me please, why this is the case?

Comment: Are you sure the instances of $w$ in the problem definition weren't supposed to be $z$ as well (or vice versa)? The solution certainly treats them as such. Also, what does $S_3^+(0)$ stand for?

Comment: Check Cauchy formula or residue calculus. Note that, $z=-2$ is a pole inside the contour.

Comment: The use of the variables is exactly the same as in my lecture notes. $S_3^+(0)$ is the path $\gamma(t) = 3e^{it}$ where $t \in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: I think it should be $e^z$ not $e^w$ according to the answer.

Comment: So maybe it is a typing mistake? If instead of $z$ there would be $w$ it would make sense to me.

Comment: So that weird $\;S_3^+(0)\;$ is just a canonical circle of radius $\;3\;$ ...What more usually is written as $\;|z|=3\;$ .

Comment: The last formula should be $$\begin{align*}
\int_{S_3^+(0)} \frac{e^w+w}{w+2} dw = 2\pi i (e^{-2}-2).
\end{align*}$$ according to the transformation definitions chosen.  Otherwise, you have an integral of the form $\int e^w\cdot f(z)dw=f(z)\int e^w dw$...

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I have another question, please see my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An integral over a closed path that does not contain any poles of an entire function (such as $e^w+w$) is zero.  This is because the path is closed, so the starting and ending points where the integral is evaluated are equivalent, and thus we have

$$\int_a^a f(z)dz=F(a)-F(a)=0$$

When the path contains a pole, as with a function like $e^w+w\over w+2$ with a path like $S_3^+(0)\to|w|=3$, then it is possible to supply an infinitesimal cut along the path and provide a different (non-circular) path which cuts out the discontinuity and results in an integral that evaluates to zero.  But this different integral is a transformation of the original, and the residue from the transformation results in the original taking on a non-zero value.

The function $e^w+w\over w+2$ over the path $S_1^+(0)\to |w|=1$ contains no pole, and therefore no transformation is necessary to obtain a path that cuts out the pole, and therefore it evaluates to zero.